# Avoiding temporary creation just for the sake of passing by value

Tags: c++

Say I have to call code into an API that I do not own. Said code accepts some parameters by value only.
Example:

```
class PleaseUseReferences
{
    void DoSometing(VectorFloat passedByValue);
}
```

on the calling side I have to now do either:

```
PleaseUseReferences pus;
pus.DoSometing(VectorFloat(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
```

or

```
PleaseUseReferences pus;
VectorFloat unnecessaryTemporary(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
pus.DoSometing(unnecessaryTemporary);
```

either way I end up with two constructor calls. One on the caller side and then another copy constructor for the argument that was passed by value.

With the understanding that

1. I cannot alter the API that was given to me, neither can I alter the code therein.
2. I know that the temporary is useless after the call.

Is there a way to save on that first constructor call ?

---

On the prompt from @cigien I tried out the two scenarios.

Here is the code I used, it demonstrates what @cigien was talking about :

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Vector
{
    public:
    Vector(int x, int y)
    {
        printf("\nConstructor");
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }
    
    Vector(const Vector& other)
    {
        printf("\nCopy Constructor");
        m_x = other.m_x;
        m_y = other.m_y;
    }
    
    static void HorriblePrint(Vector v)
    {
        printf("\nx : %d y : %d", v.m_x , v.m_y);
    }
    
    int m_x,m_y;
};

int main()
{
    printf("\nWith Temporary");
    printf("\n****************");
    Vector v(0,0);
    Vector::HorriblePrint(v);
    printf("\n****************");
    
    printf("\n\n\nWithout Temporary");
    printf("\n****************");
    Vector::HorriblePrint(Vector(1,1));
    printf("\n****************");
    
}
```

Here's the output

```
With Temporary
****************
Constructor
Copy Constructor
x : 0 y : 0
****************


Without Temporary
****************
Constructor
x : 1 y : 1
****************
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any copies with `pus.DoSometing(VectorFloat(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));` Copy elision should handle that.

Comment: What makes you think that calling the constructor is consuming a significant amount of time?

Comment: I just used VectorFloat as an example. In the real use case I am looking at, the constructor is significantly more complex @Sneftel

Comment: ^ both those points. Compiler optimizations should prevent two copies, and doing a copy probably would take a negligible amount of time anyway. Tell me, did you measure first?

Comment: There won't even be copies without compiler optimization, in the first example that uses a temporarily. Assumption not in evidence.

Comment: I'll look into copy elision . Ty @cigien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> either way I end up with two constructor calls. One on the caller side and then another copy constructor for the argument that was
> passed by value.

Not necessarily. For example:

1. If the method body is available as part of the same translation unit, the entire call might be elided.
2. If link-time optimization is enabled, then again the function might be elided.
3. As of C++17, there [seems to be language in the C++ standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) about eliding the copying of anonymous temporaries. Though I'm not 100% sure about this, and it might depend on the ABI.

Also, remember that "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Is it likely more important for that piece of your code to be readable and maintainable. I'm guessing the 3-rd party API would not force an expensive copying of some large object.

Comment: Acually, it's not "*eliding the copying of anonymous temporaries*". There's no temporary to even elide from c++17. Instead the argument is a prvalue that is only materialized where needed. And I think that applies to the OP's case.

Comment: _"I'm guessing the 3-rd party API would not force an expensive copying of some large object."_

One would hope. Sadly that is not the case here.

Comment: @Vidrohi Does the API type have a move constructor?

Comment: @Caleth It does not, but suppose it did ? (Seems you have something to share and I'm curious)

Comment: @Vidrohi if none of copy or move constructor or assignment are declared, it has implicitly generated ones. Moving a vector is a few pointer manipulations, no matter how many elements there are